# NPM Link multiple Functions / Modules in same Project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos, npm, npm-link

I have a few helper functions I'd like to have available globally in the command line. I have been able to achieve this with `npm link`, [following this tutorial](https://blog.bitsrc.io/how-to-build-a-command-line-cli-tool-in-nodejs-b8072b291f81):

```
{
  "name": "tool1",
  ...
  "bin": "./standalone-functions/tool1.js",
   ...
}
```

However, I have a few of those in a single project, e.g.
`standalone-functions/tool1.js`, `standalone-functions/tool2.js`, `standalone-functions/tool3.js` etc.

But I only have one `package.json`. So I successfully linked one. But is there a way to also link the others or would I have to have separate projects with separate `package.json`s for each?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add keys to your commands:

```
"bin": {
    "tool1": "./standalone-functions/tool1.js",
    "tool2": "./standalone-functions/tool2.js",
    "tool3": "./standalone-functions/tool3.js"       
},
```

and then execute whatever you need.